# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker popup timezone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I understand that the inlnie Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker allows you set the timezone via ng-model-options.  I'm using the datepicker-popup (ui.bootstrap.datepickerPopup) and would like to do the same, but ng-model-options doesn't appear to work.

My api returns the model in UTC time and need to ensure that the date displayed by the datepicker is also displayed in UTC.

Anybody know how to configure this?

Comment: You can insert momentjs as an inbetween...

Comment: from the docs: `ng-model`  - The date object. Must be a Javascript Date object. You may use the `uibDateParser` service to assist in string-to-object conversion.